# Is there a code-free solution which is similar to Selenium?

Tags: selenium, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests

We want to have Automated Tests for our product and we want to find a simple solution.

The solution must be easy to use and code-free, so our Product Owner can write test cases and run tests.

Has anyone been using an alternative for Selenium?

Comment: no viable open source alternative AFAIK

Comment: I've seen selenium work great when it was used on top of a solid architecture, usually based around the page object model. Otherwise they turn into maintenance nightmares just like recorded tests. I haven't really seen Selenium IDE used in a long term way other than as a stepping stone to learning how to program tests.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try Katalon Studio and Cucumber, they are free, easy to use rather than pure Selenium. They are kind of freeware tool (not open source) and have support team so you can ask for help during your test process. Cucumber is gonna have their business version soon while Katalon still remains free for all. I think you should search more info about the two tools and check out the tools to see which is better in your case. Good luck with your test!

Answer (score 0):

If you have ever thought of staying away from recording and playback, and if you get a bit knowledge on ROR, you can go ahead with Cucumber and Capybara to automate the webpages.

ref: https://www.gamesparks.com/blog/automated-testing-with-cucumber-and-capybara/

Answer (score 0):

Despite your negative experience of using Selenium tools, I would recommend looking at other approaches of using Selenium in combination with another tool. For example, in the way that combines the simplicity of Selenium actions and ability of parameterization and integration with other tools. One of such tools is [Taurus](http://www.gettaurus.org/) tool, that is simple in installation, it may execute Selenium actions (in fact you may write scripts as series of Selenium actions or compile jar file with Selenium test and use it in Taurus test) and may be used in Jenkins CI environment. More details of this solution you may find in https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-automate-jmeter-and-selenium-testing . And on the top of that you may use jmeter with these tools for load testing, if you need it.